# VBA Conditional Copy and Paste In Excel; Large Data Solution

Tags: excel, finance, vba

I have an enormous data dump that we do each month that has about 14,000 rows of data, around 12 columns wide (an entry for each month). To the left of all the data I've added a column which uses the LEFT() function to get a property code that identifies which property the row corresponds to (around 150 rows per property, roughly 100 properties, hence 15,000 rows).

We have a worksheet for each property. We update it each month with this data dump and then send it out to managers so that they can make forecasts for the rest of the year based on the month of data we just added.

I've been struggling with a solution to create a model that is more efficient than my predecessor. He made v-lookups and indexes on each of these sheets that referred to this enormous data dump. As you can guess, the file runs quite slowly.

My thought of a solution might be a macro that copy and pastes the rows of data for each property from this master sheet and pastes it onto the individual sheets (then deletes the data there to save the file some space).

That way the v-lookups would be local to each sheet and the file might run more smoothly (save for the first sequence running the macro which might take a bit of comp space).

I was hoping to get some insight on this, and if the solution is a valid one, perhaps suggestions as to coding to accomplish this.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I have found speeds up my workbooks is to pivot my data and then query the pivot table instead of using vlookups.

In your case you could create a pivot using the property ID/Name for the row Labels, Months for the Column labels then your data in the data section.

Then your formula would look something like the following:

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("value",Sheet1!$B$4,"Property","propertyName","Month","monthName")
```

This has helped me out when using a large number of vlookups on 60k rows.
This does mean an extra step of updating the pivot table each time your data updates but I think the speed of the workbook should benefit from it.

Obviously storing the data directly on the sheet would be better but writing a script to do this could be very tedious and time consuming.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I'm not great with pivot tables unfortunately, but I'm giving this a try on our Occupancy tables as it seems applicable. Thanks very much again!

Answer (score 0):

I would need some more detail of the spreadsheet to suggest big refactoring but something which can be done quickly is to use the multi column attribute of a VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(Lookup_value, Table_array, {1, 2, 3}, 0)
```

The above will return columns 1, 2 and 3 in an array. You will need to enter this as an array formula `CTRL` `SHIFT` `ENTER` across 3 cells but will have big performance enhancements if you have multiple lookups using the same lookup value but returning different columns.

Comment: Thanks Phillip, very cool solution! I hadn't known about this.